# overlaying two plots of random numbers with distinct colors

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering if there is a way in R thru which I can overlay the following two plots in a single plot in R?

Note: I need to keep each plots' display features like when you run each plot independently **Note** for example the `ylim()` in each plot must be different.

**Here is my R code:**

```
# Plot #1:   

yy = rnorm(1000)
xx = seq(-4, 4, len=1000)
plot(xx, yy, ty="p", ylim=c(-4, 4), pch=20)  ## Note ylim() here ##
abline(h=c(0, 3, -3 ), col='green', lwd=3)

# Plot # 2:

y = rcauchy(1000, 0, 1)
x = seq(-6, 6, len=1000)
plot(x, y, ty="p", col='red4', ylim=c(-10, 10), pch=20) ## Note ylim() here ##
abline(h=c(0, 2, -2), col='cyan', lwd=3)
```

Comment: I think it makes more sense to combine the data first, then generate one plot with points coloured according to some descriptive variable.

Comment: @d.b, ok I'll use points.

Comment: @neilfws, could you please explain a bit more, my goal is to show to non-stats viewer that cachy has more concentration in the middle that a standard normal?

Comment: I'd create a data frame with 3 columns: `x`, `y` and `method`. It would have 2000 rows: the first 1000 would be the x/y for rnorm, the next 1000 x/y for rcauchy. The `method` column would be the label "rnorm" (rows 1-1000) and "rcauchy" (1001 - 2000). Then I'd use `ggplot2` and either color or facet by method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base `R`:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
par(oma = c(4, 4, 0, 0))
par(mar = c(1, 1, 2, 2))
palette(colors())

# Plot #1:   
yy = rnorm(1000)
xx = seq(-4, 4, len=1000)
plot(xx, yy, ty="p", col='green4', xaxt = 'n', xlim=c(-6,6), ylim=c(-4, 4), pch=20, main='Gaussian')  ## Note ylim() here ##
abline(h=c(0, 3, -3 ), col='green1', lwd=3)

# Plot # 2:
y = rcauchy(1000, 0, 1)
x = seq(-6, 6, len=1000)
plot(x, y, ty="p", col='red4', ylim=c(-10, 10), pch=20, main='Cauchy') ## Note ylim() here ##
abline(h=c(0, 2, -2), col='red1', lwd=3)

mtext('x', side = 1, outer = TRUE, line = 2)
mtext('y', side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 2)
```

[image]
With `lattice`:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(y~x|type,
       data = rbind(data.frame(x=xx, y=yy, type='Gaussian'), 
                    data.frame(x=x, y=y, type='Cauchy')),
       ylim = list(c(-4, 4), c(-10, 10)),
       groups=type,
       col = c("red","blue"),
       pch = 19,
       layout = c(1,2), 
       scales = list(y = list(relation = "free")))
```

[image]

With `ggplot grid`

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(ggplot() + aes(x,y) + geom_point(col='red') + ylim(-10,10) + 
                   ggtitle('Cauchy') + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())), 
                ggplotGrob(ggplot() + aes(xx,yy) + geom_point(col='blue') + 
                   ggtitle('Gaussian') + xlim(c(-6,6)) + xlab('x') + ylab('y')), size = "last"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(seq(-4, 4, len = 1000), seq(-6, 6, len = 1000)),
                  y = c(rnorm(1000), rcauchy(1000, 0, 1)),
                  method = c(rep("rnorm", 1000), rep("rcauchy", 1000)))
df1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(color = method)) + facet_grid(method ~ ., scales = "free")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is a fine answer. However, to me, the use `dplyr` here perhaps adds very little.

Comment: Correct - in this case it just supplies `%>%` by importing `magrittr`. I just find it's more useful to load `dplyr` than explicitly load `magrittr`.

Comment: Sure. My point was that you aren't chaining any function calls together, so to load the package for that pipe feels rather superfluous (to me).

Comment: Sure, not required for this problem at all. Just reflects what I tend to have loaded all the time for other stuff :)